# Using Laplace Transform to solve non-linear ODE for pendulum motion and showing why it cannot be solved

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, nonlinear-system

After solving the linear version of the ODE for the Pendulum equation using Laplace transform, I tried to use LT to solve the non-linear ODE for pendulum motion.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sc0nG.png)

However, I am not very familiar with LT and so i do not really understand how to convert the non-linear term into the Laplace domain? should I just use the sin identity, even though it doesn't look right?  Once it is answered, I would also like to know why exactly it cannot be solved using LT.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i do not really understand how to convert the non-linear term into the Laplace domain.

Nobody else really does either. Computing the Laplace transform of even basic nonlinearities requires approximation via infinite series, see [here](http://13.234.104.160/index.php/m/article/view/2509). The only nonlinear way to combine functions that plays nice with the Laplace transform is convolution to my knowledge. The relation is given by
$$
\mathcal{L}[u*v](s) = \mathcal{L}[u](s)\cdot\mathcal{L}[v](s),
$$
where
$$
[u*v](t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty u(s)v(t-s)~\mathrm{d}s.
$$